# tinymce textare is displed over bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce-4

we have a problem with our website. We use bootstrap css and tinymce as richtext editor.

With bootsratp we created a navbar.

The Problem is, that when we scroll our site down, the tinymce textarea is displayed over the navbar. We tried to fix this problem with z-index but this doesn't solve anything.

[image]

Have any of you a suggestion or a solution for us?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Serviceportal 3</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-inputmask.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/sp_global_calsses.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/sp_global_functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/vendor/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/vendor/tinymce/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/bootstrap_css_reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/datepicker.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/tiny_mce_reset.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" id="navi" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <a class="brand" href="/app_dev.php/start">
                                <img src="/public/images/sp_logo.png" alt="SP" />
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                                        Options <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="/app_dev.php/global/user_settings/show">
                                                <img src="/public/images/icons/icon_user.png" alt="" />
                                                User settings        
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="/app_dev.php/global/downloads/show">
                                                <img src="/public/images/icons/icon_download.png" alt="" />
                                                Downloads        
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <img src="/public/images/icons/icon_table.png" alt="" />
                                                Registrations        
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <img src="/public/images/icons/icon_speech_bubble.png" alt="" />
                                                Contact / Feedback        
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <img src="/public/images/icons/icon_info.png" alt="" />
                                                Information        
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                    
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right navbar_pull_complete_right">
                                <li class="center_navbar_plain_text">
                                    <span style="margin-top:30px; font-size:14px;" id="date_time"></span>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/app_dev.php/login/logout">
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i></button>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:35px;"></div>
        <div id="sp_content">
            <!-- Content Container -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="form_user_settings" action="/app_dev.php/global/downloads/save_uploads" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <!-- Container with buttons -->
                <div class="well well-small">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">
                        <img src="/public/images/buttons/save.png" alt="" /><br />
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid" style="">
                    <div class="span9 well well-small">
                        <div class="well_header small">
                            Download Details
                        </div>
                        <div class="well_content">

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label sp_loginpage_label" for="name">Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" required value="versuch">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label sp_loginpage_label" for="version">Version</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="version" name="version" required value="versuch">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label sp_loginpage_label" for="description">Description</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea class="richtext_editor" required name="description" id="description">versich</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label sp_loginpage_label" for="version_history">Version History</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea class="richtext_editor" required name="version_history" id="version_history">asdasfc</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label sp_loginpage_label" for="download_counter">DownloadCounter</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="download_counter" name="download_counter" readonly value="5">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <!-- Container for Document Ready functions -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // ### Initialisation from TinyMCE Richtexteditor ### //
                tinymce.init({
                    mode: "specific_textareas",
                    editor_selector: "richtext_editor",
                    theme: "modern",
                    width: 360,
                    height: 200,
                    resize: false,
                    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
                    style_formats: [
                        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                        {title: 'Table styles'},
                        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please provide a working example on a temporary url?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a oportunety to upload this site for external use, but we edited the Post and added the code from the site.